# Deploying a Vue.js/Go container to heroku not working

Tags: docker, go, nginx, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my project that uses Vuejs in the frontend(running in localhost:8080 and hardcoded to send ws and http requests to localhost:5000. It also uses vue router to handle routing) and a go websocket server(at localhost:5000) for the backend. I have tried deploying the git repository but heroku wanted the repository to be in one language so I am currently using a multistage docker build since I have divided it into a frontend and backend directory.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1.16-alpine as go-build
ADD . /build
WORKDIR /build/vc-server
COPY vc-server/*.go ./
COPY vc-server/go.mod ./
COPY vc-server/go.sum ./
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build

FROM node:14-alpine AS vue-build
WORKDIR /build/vc-frontend
COPY vc-frontend/. ./
COPY vc-frontend/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine
COPY --from=vue-build /build/vc-frontend/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=go-build /build/vc-server/vc-server ./
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY entrypoint.sh .
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh** - Serves the frontend dist using nginx and also runs the go binary.

```
#!/bin/sh
./vc-server & 
sed -i -e 's/$PORT/'"$PORT"'/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen $PORT;
    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
```

If I try to build this and run it locally using the command `docker run -it -e 'PORT=80' -p 8080:80 -p 5000:5000 --rm vc:latest`
then the app is working fine on port 8080. When I release this container, there is an application error and this is what the logs show.

```
2021-07-18T11:12:47.572098+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./entrypoint.sh`
2021-07-18T11:12:50.572311+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021/07/18 11:12:50 [warn] 7#7: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
2021-07-18T11:12:50.572313+00:00 app[web.1]: nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
2021-07-18T11:12:50.573959+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021/07/18 11:12:50 [emerg] 7#7: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
2021-07-18T11:12:50.573960+00:00 app[web.1]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
2021-07-18T11:12:50.635213+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-07-18T11:12:50.719062+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-07-18T11:12:55.716826+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vc-test.herokuapp.com request_id=9ece7adc-3caa-4ca0-873b-5bbd567d9759 fwd="94.205.20.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-07-18T11:12:56.461615+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vc-test.herokuapp.com request_id=35e06cac-eef8-40a1-8094-93599a692a33 fwd="94.205.20.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

How do I fix this or is there a better way to deploy a project like this? I've gone through tons of github repos using similar technologies but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: The message from heroku logs says something about user directive so either you didn't paste here a full config or your Dockerfile not build proper config. Worth to mention that Heroku supports only single port per web application. So you probably must proxy websocket connection through nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Containers dont run with root privileges on heroku

read more here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

`We strongly recommend testing images locally as a non-root user, as containers are not run with root privileges on Heroku.`

That's the reason why it cant access `/usr` folder and port :80 fails to bind